# Would an Israeli staying in Diaspora need to make Eruv Tavshilin?

Tags: yom-tov, chutz-laaretz, eruv-tavshilin

I understand that if an Israeli is outside of Israel during Yom Tov, he may not perform melachot on the 2nd day of Yom Tov.

Does this include *hachana* (preparing on Yom Tov for the next day or for Shabbat?) Specifically, if the 2nd day of Yom Tov were to be on a Friday, would the Israeli need to make *Eruv Tavshilin*? Or do the rules of *hachanah* not apply to him as it is not actually Yom Tov for him, but he is not doing melachot because he must follow the minhag of where he is?

Comment: Isn’t it “not really Yom Tov” for anyone, and we’re all just following the minhag of where we are?

Comment: @Loani Not exactly. Israelis never had the rule of having to keep 2 days Yom Tov in the first place. So, there is no minhag for them to follow, now, even with a fixed calendar. When they are in a community outside of Israel they are following a different rule of following the minhag of the community they are in to avoid *mar'it ayin* and *do not create factions."